# Will preventive measures of COVID-19 pandemic ever lessen to a great extent in the most parts of the world?

Tags: covid-19, coronavirus, covid-19-datasets

People always say in hard times that "this too shall pass". Is it right for COVID-19 pandemic (please see what I mean by pandemic here. My English is a bit weak so this word might not be right) as well?

I know we can't predict whether there will be a vaccine or not, ever or the coronavirus will vanish (and eventually the disease) after some years.

But I guess this question can be answered as it is more about the pandemic.

Actually I'm not really sure about the word pandemic here. So let me explain what I want to know in following way:

What I mean is that *most of the world wearing masks, maintaining social distancing, washing hands frequently, having a state of constant fear about getting infected anytime (unlike other diseases), working from home, not partying with friends in groups, hospitals full of patients and dead bodies on roads...* **Will these things remain forever in most parts of world Or will it end to a great extent and life will become almost normal like before, maybe after 5-10-25 years later (let's assume there's no other similar disease like this in future)?**

Or this statement is very true for this pandemic as well... This too shall pass?

Comment: Some countries are about to have Avifavir!!! :D That being said, what we can say about COVID-19 is that of course, won't last forever

Comment: @América is Avifavir a cure for covid?

Comment: According to [Rusia enviará a América Latina su medicamento contra el covid-19](https://youtu.be/DV4-kogEXnk?t=13) is for _prevention_, diagnosis and _treatment_. 90% of efficacy. The disease is reduced from 9 to 4 days, the high fever was reduced from 6 to 3 days and 65% of the patients were recovered from COVID-19 in 4 days. ((Sorry for my bad translation))

Comment: If that's true, it's really great :D

Comment: yes, it is, good news! finally! .I've some corrections: _mean_ duration of illness was reduced from 9 to 4 days, _mean_ duration of high fever was reduced from 6 to 3 days.

Comment: @América but I read this article which makes me doubt about it :( https://www.news18.com/news/world/russia-defends-anti-viral-drug-avifavir-as-covid-19-death-toll-passes-11000-2710589.html

If this drug was useful, wouldn't death cases decrease? No?